# What RFC's are good to know as a web-developer?

Tags: rfc

What [RFC's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request_for_Comments) are good to know as a web-developer?

Answer (score 6):

[RFC 2616 about HTTP](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) would be relevant, but I am not really sure RFCs are the best way to learn about web applications. Some RFCs are long, very detailed and not really useful as a general introduction IMO.